# Space in Mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have varchar data type field in mysql db.

I want to treat space as a character and store in db.

Example: String =Apple
In the above example i have 4 spaces after the word Apple and that should be stored in db.

Comment: What is the problem or question?

Comment: And what prevents you from doing so?

Comment: You might want to share some information on how you are communicating with the database and provide some code / queries to examine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MySQL has explicit functions for trimming the spaces from a string, it seems to me that it is supposed to honor the spaces in your strings if not instructed to trim them?

EDIT: Below is the rest of my answer. This seems to be based on an erroneous assumption about MySQLs string handling. Sorry about that.

Are you using ' around your strings in your queries?

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (`str` = 'my string with spaces       ')
```

Otherwise the spaces will not be regarded as part of the string, I think...

EDIT: As pointed out, the above example would throw an error if the quotes were removed, but it wouldn't if the string was a single word plus spaces:

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (`str` = 'apple       ') // inserts 'apple       '
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (`str` = apple       ) // inserts 'apple'
```

Comment: Otherwise you will get sql exceptions, I'm sure... :)

Comment: No, you won't if your string consists of a single word plus spaces, like 'apple   '.

Comment: INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (`testfield`='apple      ') => Inserted rows: 1 (Query took 0.0002 sec);INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (`testfield`=apple      ) => #1054 - Unknown column 'apple' in 'field list'

Answer (score 7):

I think space is stored in a column of type varchar unless you use trim method to remove the space.

Comment: Space definately is stored unless you trim it before inserting or updating the row.

Answer (score 1):

You can just store them like this
`INSERT INTO sometable(somecolumn) VALUES ('test     ');`

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 5.0+, trailing spaces are (correctly according to the SQL standard) retained on strings.

On earlier versions, they were erroneously stripped.

In either case, as per the SQL standard, comparisons with = will ignore trailing spaces. If for some reason you want to compare the trailing spaces, use something like

```
SELECT ... FROM t WHERE col='Hello ' AND LENGTH(col) = LENGTH('Hello ')
```

Which of course will only give you the rows where the trailing space is the same as well.